# How to update Tracker.Current

Tags: xdb, xconnect

I have a `Sitecore 9 form` where a user submits a form and that contact will be saved in `xDB`. At the time of submitting I am checking in `xDB` is duplicate contact exist, on basis of First name, Last name, Email and Identifier source.

I am able to get duplicate contact using the below query:

```
    IAsyncQueryable<XConnect.Contact> query = client.Contacts
                .Where(c => c.Identifiers.Any(i => i.Source == "XYZ") &&
                       c.GetFacet<EmailAddressList>(EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey).PreferredEmail.SmtpAddress == emailID
                       && c.GetFacet<PersonalInformation>(PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey).FirstName == firstname
                && c.GetFacet<PersonalInformation>(PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey).LastName == lastname
                ).
                WithExpandOptions(new ContactExpandOptions( PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey, EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey));
```

***Problem***

1. Anonymous user is coming in the website and interact with the page and trigger some `goals`
2. Anonymous has a contact ID
3. Then user visits my form which I am talking above, here they submit a form, now if a user is a duplicate I am updating facets.
4. My facets are updated for an existing contact
5. After 20 mins, when the session expires, it is creating anonymous contact as well in `xDB` and also saving `Interaction` for anonymous user.

I want anonymous user should not create in `xDB` and `Interaction` should save for existing contact only.

I have tried to use `LoadContact` method but still, it is not working

```
  manager.RemoveFromSession(CurrentTracker.Contact.ContactId);
   CurrentTracker.Session.Contact = manager.LoadContact(new Guid(existingContact.Id.ToString()));
```

Comment: you need to identify contact as soon as you know the current visitor is a know contact. please see this documentation https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/identifying-contacts.html

Comment: I tried to use that but no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue using below points:

1. Saved Anonymous contact first because Anonymous contact is still in Session
2. Then get existing contact from the database and updated facets
3. Merged existing contact into Anonymous contact using Merge API https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/merge-contacts.html

Now I have Interaction as well as updated facets.